# How can I get the saved version of an ICompilationUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

An analysis we run currently has an issue with unsaved files in Eclipse...when we visit the compilation units of a Java project, if there's a file that is currently being edited, that has unsaved changes, it seems that we get a copy with unsaved changes.

The contract of our tool, however, is that it will match the saved version of your code, and update at each save.

Supposing I have an ICompilationUnit that has unsaved changes, how can I get the version of that compilation unit representing the current saved file?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `ICompilationUnit#getPrimary()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you are right as by slide 19 here: http://www.slideshare.net/aupsy/how-to-train-the-jdt-dragon

Comment: Hmm...I was hopeful that this would be the answer, although the API is pretty coy about it if it does do that...but what slide 19 says makes me even more doubtful that I was already: "Primary working copy: shared buffer shown by all editors". What I'm looking for is the current saved version, which is typically not shown by any Eclipse editor. Either that slide was misleading or this isn't the answer.

Comment: Hmm, so what about retrieving the underlying `IResource` associated with the `ICompilationUnit` that you have and load it from the disk ?

Comment: I need it as an ICompilationUnit in order to parse it and produce an AST, the underlying resource isn't very useful unless I can get an ICompilationUnit based on it.

Comment: You can parse the underlying IResource: `JavaCore.create(resource)` will return an `ICompilationUnit` for your .java file.